# Horizontal listview with OnScrollListener

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I need sync scroll of 2 listViews (vertical and horizontal)

I tried several libraries for the horizontal listview, but no library implements OnScrollListener()

https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android

need this callback to scroll vertical list when scoll the horizontal list...

how can I do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little bit of code for this exact thing a while back. Check it out here https://github.com/slightfoot/android-tandem-scroll

Just duplicate https://github.com/slightfoot/android-tandem-scroll/blob/master/Library/src/com/demondevelopers/tandemscroll/TandemScrollView.java file and make it extend HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: thaks! question: i can replace this "addView(layout);" for code in xml?  
<com.TandemScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
      <com.bminds.mdlz.utils.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDays" />
</com.TandemScrollView> 
?????

Comment: Yes. I don't see any reason why not.